# hash value different between mysqladmin and password() funciton

Tags: linux, mysql, mysqladmin

I've compiled & installed a mysql-5.1.59 on a x86_64 linux server.

First I set root password in cli and login:

```
$ bin/mysqladmin -uroot password 'somepass'
$ bin/mysql -uroot -p 'somepass'
mysql>
```

Login succeed!

Then I created a user using SQL statements:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'myuser'@'localhost' identified by 'somepass';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

The password is exactly the same as root.

But after I queried:

```
mysql> select host,user,password from mysql.user;
```

I noticed that **the password values of the two account are not the same**.
And I tried login mysql with myuser but failed.

By the way if I change the root password this way:

```
mysql> update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('somepass') where user='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Then I can't login mysql with root anymore:

```
$ bin/mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This never happens on my other servers. It seems like the issue has something to do with the os.
How could the hashed values different between each other?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the MySQL documentation is a bit sparse in this area, I would assume it's salting the passwords.

For security, a random value called "salt" is typically added to a password before it is hashed. With the salt, the resulting hash on the same password is very different.

From Wikipedia:

> The benefit provided by using a salted password is making a lookup table assisted dictionary attack against the stored values impractical, provided the salt is large enough. That is, an attacker would not be able to create a precomputed lookup table (i.e. a rainbow table) of hashed values (password + salt), because it would take too much space. A simple dictionary attack is still very possible, although much slower since it cannot be precomputed.

Comment: It seems like each of the two ways mentioned in the question uses different salt.

Comment: Well it finally turns out that it was my fault...
My password has a backslash in it and I forgot to escape it in the SQL statement...

Comment: If you're using salted passwords, every password would have a unique salt. Again I don't know if this is how MySQL's passwords work but I'm glad you got your issue resolved.